# How to post XML string to MVC controller having parameter type HttpPostedFileBase using HttpWeRequest

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I want to do performance testing of my API which is use to upload XML file using HttpWebRequest.

**MVC Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
     public bool UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
        if(file!=null){
         ///do something
         }
        }
```

**Web Request Code**

```
    string XMLstring = <Details><Name>ABC</Name><City>Mumbai</City></Details>;
string URL = "localhost:1010/ControllerName/UploadFile"   
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                try
                {
                    byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XMLstring);

                    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
                    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
                    }
                    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                    {

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
```

So Above API is called but it shows null value in parameter.

Comment: What parameter?   You may want to use a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark to help debug issues.

Comment: Sorry, It is MVC controller method, and I want to send XML string to controller using HttpRequest

Comment: I have no idea what parameter you are referring to.  I suggest using a sniffer so you ican see exactly what is being transferred.